# chrome.events for specifi URL instead of content_script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I''m trying to create an extension that redirect PHP files in my WAMP folder to a localhost URL. As far as I understood reading Chrome documentation the best practice will be to use Chrome events with a URL filter, the code I'm using right now does work but if possible I prefer to use a more performant way, can anyone suggest how?

eventPage.js:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split( '/www' ); /*get current url and splits it*/ 
var newpath = "http://localhost" + path[1];  /*change the varaible to localhost url insted of file/// */
window.open(newpath,"_self"); /*open the new URL in the same tab*/
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "PHP localhost Redirect",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Automatically Redirect a url to localhost if is a php file in the wamp www folder",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["file:///C:/wamp/www/*.php"],
      "js": ["eventPage.js"]
    }
    ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon19.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs" , "file:///C:/wamp/www/*"]
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question. The text part is not readable, so I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to add permission for a specific url in manifest.json, instead of permitting all urls. You can visit [manifest.json - permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) for more understanding. Thus in this case all actions will be performed on a specific url, if that url is registered in manifest.json